# Griddb time series graphical data representation

Tags: cross-domain, apex, embedding, griddb

I have been working with the griddb  and looking to make a dashboard for the data being consumed with it. How to approach this using the griddb console or any other setup which can be used to integrate it into a dashboard to monitor real-time data captured in my griddb database?

The application is an apex application and I have been trying multiples solutions to make it happen.

I am trying to showcase the data getting inserted into my database griddb and run a graph of the time series data from various sensors.